# Possibility of flyway custom clean script

Tags: oracle, flyway

Our Oracle database uses the "Text data dictionary" Module. Part of the set-up creates a preference.

```
    -- create preference...
    begin
          ctx_ddl.create_preference(....);
      ctx_ddl.set_attribute(...);
    end;
```

The problem is that the flyway clean goal does not drop this preference.

So, my question: 
is it possible to add/configure an extra clean-up script to remove non-table/index/view objects? Or is there any other way to achieving this?

EDIT: I've just realised the same goes for jobs in the scheduler. They are also not deleted by the flyway clean. For example:

```
      sys.dbms_scheduler.create_job(
      job_name => 'MY_JOB',
      job_type => 'plsql_block',
      job_action => 'begin ctx_ddl.sync_index('...'); end;',
      repeat_interval => 'freq=secondly;interval=60',
      comments => 'run every minute',
      enabled => true);
    end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Custom clean scripts are not supported out of the box.

You would have to wrap the Flyway.clean() execution with your own cleanup code.

Comment: Where would we do this? Are we talking about a maven excution or java execution? Would this be a viable solution for the commandline-tool?

Comment: You can wrap the command-line script with another one, or run the maven sql plugin in the same lifecycle phase as Flyway or simply wrap the Java call.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you can use [Flyway callbacks](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/callbacks). The `afterClean` callback is what you're looking for.